# Javascript check if div element is empty

Tags: javascript

I have **variable** which hold **div element.** In Javascript  I want to check, how to validate if div element holds any child nodes or is emtpy? The response can be in TRUE or FALSE

I have tried with my options from google but not getting exact results for javascript. please suggest me if anyone has better input.

NOTE: Validation has to be done in Javascript not in Jquery and div doesn't have any ID here..

`var ele = "<div class='....'></div>"`

Comment: The code here shows a variable the contains a string - not a **div element**.

Answer (score 0):

Your code here shows a string variable, not a div element.

Otherwise simply get your div element using (for example)

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("divId");
```

And then simply check if it's content is empty or not :

```
if (myDiv.innerHTML == "")
{
    //myDiv is empty
}
else
{
    //myDiv isn't empty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is putting your string inside a $() selector. Then you can use css selectors etc for checking if it is empty:

```
var ele1 = "<div class='myclass'></div>";

if ($(ele1).is(':empty')) {
    console.log('1 is empty!');
} else {
    console.log('1 is not empty!');
}

var ele2 = "<div class='myclass'>Duh, not empty at all!</div>";

if ($(ele2).is(':empty')) {
    console.log('2 is empty!');
} else {
    console.log('2 is not empty!');
}
```